# Laravel ¿que es un guard?

Tags: php, laravel

Estaba viendo como funcionan los middlewares dentro de una aplicacion laravel, y encontre que dentro de la misma esta la sentencia llamada guard pero no tengo idea de como usarlo o como funciona, ya que para validar inicios de sesion en cada controlador tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
  public function __construct(){

    if (Session::has('sessionname')) {
      return true;
    }
    else{

      echo "<script> alert('No has Iniciado Sesion');
   window.location='http://refaccionaria.proyectotic.online/refaccionaria/public/acceso';
   </script>";
    exit;
    }
```

Comment: aqui la respuesta, a la misma pregunta en ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896130/laravel-what-is-a-guard

Comment: documentacion https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#adding-custom-guards